# Disk label changes when system is rebooted while setting up Fedora CoreOS 39

Tags: devices, coreos

I am installing a Fedora CoreOS v39.2024030 on a bare metal system (PowerEdge server) through a iDRac interface.

It's a two-step process:

1. Here it's needed to boot the system into a LiveISO (virtual cd-rom) and perform the install step:

   ```
   coreos-installer install /dev/sda --ignition-url http://filepath.ign
   ```

   Once file system is copied, it reboots to perform the installation.
2. Reboot and perform automated installation based on ignition file instructions.

My issue is that when I first boot the system with liveCD, it shows my two disks (block storage names) **sda and sdb**, but when the system reboots for the second phase, those disk names change to **sdb and sdc**.
The reason is that step 1 creates some temporary disk of 0B which sits at sda.

Because of this, the setup fails with the error "Problem opening /dev/sda".

How can I make sure the disk label does not change on reboot?

[image]

References: [Official Documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/bare-metal/)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot be sure that `/dev/sdc` or whatever will always be `/dev/sdc`. Your case is a good example of that.

For this reason, it is safer to reference devices by their UUID, via `/dev/disk/by-id/` or `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`. Use

```
lsblk -f
```

to see the UUID of all your connected disks.

Comment: i do not see any other label or uuid assigned to these disks. lsblk -f shows only NAME. I'll see how i can use by-id.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly comment, but its too big to fit in the box.

The term "label" in relation to disks is used to describe something other than how you are using it. The values "sda", "sdb" are device names. These are based on the identifiers discovered by the hardware during POST (first discovered disk is identified as "0", second "1" etc). The device names are therefore expected to change when you change the hardware configuration.

There are several solutions to the problem of ensuring that a block device has a consistent address. These are mediated by symlinks in the /dev filesystem. One is to place a small string of data at the start of each volume - THAT is what is referred to as a label. Underneath /dev/disk you'll see several folders - each represent a different addressing method. Here I have:

```
by-id  by-label  by-partuuid  by-path  by-uuid
```

When someone writes an installer, they don't know how the system will be configured but *expect* that the configuration will not change during the installation and hence will use the base naming early in the installation.

You have some weird stuff going on if your hardware configuration is changing without actually plugging/unplugging stuff. Did you remove the installation media at the reboot? (the sdX names *should* only be applied to attached SAS/SATA disks, not USB disks or optical drives). Using iDRAC implies you are doing this remotely - are you using some network device as a fake disk? I'm not specifically familiar with iDRAC, but with iLO and IPMI you can explicitly set the type of device (as optical media / USB / attached device).

Comment: That was informative! yes sda,sdb are virtual disks and these are block device names not labels as such, i am doing remote setup, sr0 is iso mounted as virtualcdrom. I'll check how i can use by-id. atleast for now i cant see any other label or id to these block devices (lsblk -f)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `lsblk` output shows the `sda` as follows:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    1     0B  0 disk
```

RM = Removable, like a (virtual) CD-ROM drive. Size 0 bytes, like a CD-ROM drive with no disc in it. This looks like an iDRAC virtual CD-ROM drive, with the virtual disc ejected!

After the first installation phase, the installer may have sent the "eject" command to the iDRAC virtual CD-ROM, as usual, but it looks like it did not cause the virtual CD-ROM to completely disable itself.

Because the iDRAC virtual CD is often used to override the normal installed OS for maintenance purposes, the designers of the system firmware have apparently made it appear as the first storage device if active at system boot time.

So, after the first installation phase, as soon as the system goes down to reboot, you should immediately *turn off the iDRAC virtual CD-ROM*. If that does not help, you might even try disconnecting the iDRAC console connection until the CoreOS kernel has booted up. With the iDRAC virtual CD/console disconnected, the virtual CD-ROM drive should not be visible for the system, and so the CoreOS kernel should label the disks as `sda` and `sdb`.

Once the CoreOS kernel has booted up and assigned those device names to the disks, reconnecting the iDRAC console and even re-activating the virtual CD-ROM feature should cause the iDRAC virtual CD-ROM be detected as `sdc`. Since the device nodes `sda` and `sdb` will now be already assigned to disks at that point, the virtual CD-ROM will get bumped to the first free device node `sdc` even though it might occupy the numerically first SATA channel at the hardware level.

After you get your CoreOS installed, and can SSH into the OS, you might want to run `lspci`, `lsusb` and `lsblk` (maybe also `lsinput` if available) with the iDRAC console disconnected, then do the same again with the iDRAC connected without activating the virtual CD-ROM, and again with the virtual CD-ROM feature activated, and compare the results. Note any additional devices that appear when the iDRAC console and/or the virtual CD-ROM is connected.

Once you understand exactly what kind of virtual devices appear into the system when using each part of the iDRAC functionality, you'll be able to use iDRAC more effectively.

Comment: I can definitely remove the cd rom, issue is not with cdrom but with 0MB drive getting created which changes the block storage names.